# converting integers to chars in C(according to ASCII table)

Tags: c, integer, chars

been searching everywhere, but couldn't the correct answer.

the problem is pretty simple:

i have to convert ASCII integer values into char's.
for example, according to ASCII table, 108 stands for 'h' char. But when i try to convert it like this:

```
int i = 108
char x = i
```

and when I printf it, it shows me 's', no matter what number i type in(94,111...).

i tried this as well:

```
int i = 108;
char x = i + '0'
```

but i get the same problem! by the way, i have no problem in converting chars into integers, so i don't get where's the problem :/
thanks in advance

Comment: Please copy and paste actual code; these fragments could not have been compiled, and it doesn't usually make sense to try to debug something that has never been run.

Comment: Note that [decimal value 108 is actually lowercase `l`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters), not `s` or `h`. Where did you find `s` or `h`?

Comment: please show us how your printf call.

Comment: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/ascii-codes-108.html

Comment: sorry, 108 stands for 'l', but it doesn't make a difference. full code looks like: 
int i = 108;
char x = i;

printf("%s\n", x);

and when i compile it, it shows 's' char(and no errors), i don't know why..

Comment: @Rytis: `%s` means print as string. A character is not a string. A string is terminated by a `\0`, for instance. You'll want to use `%c` for printing a single character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is how you do it. You probably want it unsigned, though.

Maybe your `printf` is wrong?

The following is an example of it working:

```
// Print a to z.
int i;
for (i = 97; i <= 122; i++) {
    unsigned char x = i;
    printf("%c", x);
}
```

This prints `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` as expected. (See it at [ideone](http://ideone.com/xhfrc))

Note, you could just as well `printf("%c", i);` directly; `char` is simply a smaller integer type.

If you're trying to do `printf("%s", x);`, note that this is not correct. `%s` means print as string, however a character is not a string.

If you do this, it'll treat the value of `x` as a memory address and start reading a string from there until it hits a `\0`. If this merely resulted in printing `s`, you're lucky. You're more likely to end up getting a segmentation fault doing this, as you'll end up accessing some memory that is most likely not yours. (And almost surely not what you want.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your `printf` statement is incorrect.

Doing `printf("%c", c)` where c has the value 108 will print the letter `l`... If you look at http://www.asciitable.com/ you'll see that 108 is not `h` ;)

Comment: it works! i wrote %s instead of %c, stupid me. thank you very much and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Does explain why you were seeing `s` every time! Not a waste of time at all, everybody makes those mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your printf statement looks like this:

```
printf("s", x);
```

..when in fact you probably meant:

```
printf("%s", x);
```

...which is still wrong; this is expecting a string of characters e.g:

```
char* x = "Testing";
printf("%s", x);
```

What you really want is this:

```
int i = 108;
char x = i + '0';
printf("%c", x);
```

...which on my system outputs `£`